# C# program to pick out eye coordinates to crop image

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2010

I am currently doing a project where I am using 3 webcams and take a photo on button click. The image will be saved to specific folder on my hard drive `C:\`. That is working fine now. I would now like to display the image in another `NEW WINDOWS FORM` and I will be able to pick out eye coordinates of the person in the image saved. The purpose of picking out the eye coordinates is to ensure it is able to go through the normalization process for facial recognition purposes.

Now, my main issue is how is it possible for me to pick out the eye coordinates from an picture box in C# before coordinates would be saved to python scripts and normalization process would occur. If anyone has done anything similar, please give me some advice.

Comment: Keep it in one language. That's just a tip. You can write C code in Python for performance reasons.. But that's as far as mixing languages should go.

Comment: Hi, so is it impossible to use C# with python? Will there be any negative effects?

Comment: @user3766178 A better question would be 'is it possible to use .Net stack in python?'

Comment: C# is great and all if you're about to integrate multiple Windows services etc. But you're better off with C/C++ or pure Python for this particular task. And I'd say it's near impossible to combine C# and Python, but then agan I havn't really tried.. Mostly because i don't spend my time in Windows environments :)